# Probe Request Frames

Tags: ieee-802.11, mac-address, packet-analysis, access-point

**OBJECTIVE**

The end goal here s to build a python program with Scapy that detects all access points within range of my machine.

**UNDERSTANDING**

I understand this is normally done by using [802.11 Frame Types](http://www.wi-fiplanet.com/tutorials/article.php/1447501/Understanding-80211-Frame-Types.htm), specifically probe request frames and probe responses.

**MISUNDERSTANDING**

However, I seem to be missing a concept.

With scapy I can send out a probe request frame like so:

```
local_mac = 'AA:BA:CA:DA:EA:FA'
dest_mac = 'AB:BB:CB:DB:EB:FB'
srp(Dot11(type=0, subtype=4, addr1 = local_mac, addr2 = dest_mac), iface = 'wlan0')
```

As you can see, I need the destination mac address of the access point I have not discovered yet. So, how should I already know the destination mac address before discovering the access point?

How is this done in other applications that achieve this result -- such as the list of access points that my computer provides for me to possibly connect to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obviously don't know the AP's MAC address, so you want to send it to everybody.  You use the broadcast address FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF.  Every device will receive this packet, and APs will respond with a probe response.

Listening for beacons is not enough.  Often, SSID's are hidden, so you have to actively probe for them.

Comment: That is something some applications actively do. For the last question, a lot of OSes passively listen for beacons to populate the list of available SSIDs.

Comment: Would I need two wireless cards for this ... one to monitor and one to transmit?

Comment: No.  You send requests, and then listen for responses.

Answer (score 0):

The way to get the MAC addresses of WAPs is to listen for beacon frames sent by the WAPs.

This is from the link in your question:

> **Beacon frame:** The access point periodically sends a beacon frame to announce its presence and relay information, such as timestamp,
>   SSID, and other parameters regarding the access point to radio NICs
>   that are within range. Radio NICs continually scan all 802.11 radio
>   channels and listen to beacons as the basis for choosing which access
>   point is best to associate with.